# grabbing info from a table with loops (python)

Tags: python

- I am trying to analyze some information in this text file (one of
  many I want to analyze in the same format)
- the .txt file has a table in it with the info I need
- The table will always have 16 columns but the number of rows will vary
- The table has columns that are separated by pipes "|" and rows that are separated by these:'+--------+--------+'
- I split the file (.split('+---+')) into a list ('newlist') where each
  element is a row (row 1 = newlist[0])
- I cut off the file after the
  table ends (where '..image::' is)
- Now I want to split the rows into
  their columns I can easily do this with .split('|')
- I created some loops that work nicely and account for a variable
  number of rows
- def row() takes the newlist into list_i list_i is a
  list where each element is the contents of one box in that row (used
  split('|') For this particular test file I can go up to row(29)

  - I'm interested in the column-wise data The next loop creates a list
    with column info def column() looks at all the rows in range(number
    of rows) and pulls the same index for all of those rows. so column(9)
    will pull row(0)[9], row(1)[9]....all the way to the last row
  - my problem is that this works well until I get to column(9) and then
    it says list index out of range
- sorry I know this has been asked many times but cant figure out whats wrong

  Thank you!

input file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_JDBrcvs5VcRU1ueE5kUlVoYlk

```
    f = open("999A.txt")


    text_in_file = f.read().strip().split('+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+')
    f.close()

    newlist = []

    for item in text_in_file:
        newlist.append(item)
    matching = [s for s in newlist if ".. image::" in s]

    for item in newlist:
        if newlist.index(item) >= newlist.index(matching[0]):
            newlist.remove(item)


    num_rows = len(newlist) - 1


    def row(i):
        row_i = newlist[i+1]
        list_i = list(row_i.strip().split('|'))
        return list_i[1:17]

    def column(i):
        list_i = []
        for z in range(num_rows):
            list_i.append(row(z)[i])
        return list_i[1:]

    for i in range(30):
        print(row(i))
    print("columns:")
    for i in range(16):
        print(column(i))
```

Comment: Please show your input file; or better, show a small version of your input file that produces the same problem.

Comment: I would just ignore all lines that don't start with `|` and split the ones that do on `|`... that seems to be all that you need to get the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The table will always have 16 columns

Not true, you only have 8 headers, so you are going to get a index error on that line.

```
|  *L1 barcodes*  |  *L2 barcodes*  |  *L3 barcodes*  |  *L4 barcodes*  |  *L5 barcodes*  |  *L6 barcodes*  |  *L7 barcodes*  |  *L8 barcodes*  |
| CTCTCT | 27.66% | GTTTCG | 9.04%  | NNNNNN | 3.67%  | ATTCGG | 7.41%  | GACGAT | 6.90%  | GAACCC | 13.29% | GTAACA | 9.50%  | ATCGCC | 56.24% |
```

Sample code to see that

```
with open("999A.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("|"):
            print line
```

If you would like to only get lines that have the required number of columns, then you'll need to check the length of the split row like so.

```
data = []
with open("999A.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("|"):
            cols = line.split("|")[1:-1] # remove outside empty strings
            cols = list(map(str.strip, cols)) # strip the remaining strings
            if len(cols) == 16 and not all(x == '' for x in cols):
                # keep rows with 16 columns and no empty strings
                data.append(cols)

for row in data:
    # do something
    print(row)
```

Sample output

```
['CTCTCT', '27.66%', 'GTTTCG', '9.04%', 'NNNNNN', '3.67%', 'ATTCGG', '7.41%', 'GACGAT', '6.90%', 'GAACCC', '13.29%', 'GTAACA', '9.50%', 'ATCGCC', '56.24%']
['TGTGTG', '27.54%', 'ATTCCT', '5.78%', 'TTCAGA', '3.11%', 'CGAATC', '6.70%', 'ATTCGG', '6.45%', 'TGCTGT', '13.18%', 'TGCTGT', '8.64%', 'GCTATT', '9.98%']
['ACACAC', '22.70%', 'ATGTCA', '4.47%', 'AGGTTT', '3.01%', 'GACGAT', '6.36%', 'CCATTA', '6.37%', 'TTCAGA', '12.19%', 'CCTGAG', '7.82%', 'CCGAGT', '8.79%']
['GAGAGA', '16.18%', 'GTGGCC', '4.06%', 'CCTGAG', '2.71%', 'GCTATT', '6.26%', 'TTGCCG', '6.23%', 'CCTGAG', '11.42%', 'AAGCTC', '7.77%', 'TAATAG', '5.72%']
['', '', 'GNNTNG', '3.96%', 'GAACCC', '2.47%', 'AGTAGC', '6.11%', 'TAGGCT', '6.14%', 'AGGTTT', '11.39%', 'GAACCC', '7.62%', 'CCATTA', '3.70%']
['', '', 'GTGAAA', '3.47%', '', '', 'CCATTA', '6.10%', 'GCCTAA', '6.07%', 'GTAACA', '11.36%', 'CTTAAA', '7.56%', '', '']
```

You probably also will want to group each pair of elements in your list to keep the initial 8 columns

That would look like so

```
...
# keep rows with 16 columns and no empty strings
cols_iter = iter(cols)
data.append(list(zip(cols_iter, cols_iter)))
```

With output like this

```
[('CTCTCT', '27.66%'), ('GTTTCG', '9.04%'), ('NNNNNN', '3.67%'), ('ATTCGG', '7.41%'), ('GACGAT', '6.90%'), ('GAACCC', '13.29%'), ('GTAACA', '9.50%'), ('ATCGCC', '56.24%')]
[('TGTGTG', '27.54%'), ('ATTCCT', '5.78%'), ('TTCAGA', '3.11%'), ('CGAATC', '6.70%'), ('ATTCGG', '6.45%'), ('TGCTGT', '13.18%'), ('TGCTGT', '8.64%'), ('GCTATT', '9.98%')]
```

Expanding on that, you can print each element

```
for row in data:
    # do something
    for seq, percent in row:
        if not '' in {seq, percent}:
            print(seq, percent)
```

Outputs

```
CTCTCT 27.66%
GTTTCG 9.04%
NNNNNN 3.67%
ATTCGG 7.41%
GACGAT 6.90%
```